# PHPExcel xls file reading and HTML display

Tags: php, html, excel, google-chrome

I'm losing time as hell using this PHPExcel lib. 
My code is widely inspired from models which are available in the lib.

+The mission is :

-To read an *.xls file with PHP

-Display it in a navigator in HTML

For the moment, I just can read the file successfully (with a "createReader" method of PHPExcel_IOFactory instance). But for the HTML display, I'm in a pretty good crap. At attempt of code correction gives me this error:

> " Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PHPExcel_Calculation_Exception' with
>   message 'Réalisé S03!P374 -> Réalisé S03!P374 -> Formula Error:
>   Unexpected ,' "

Here is the code :

```
<?phperror_reporting(E_ALL);
set_time_limit(0);
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
/** Include path **/
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . '../../../Classes/');

/** PHPExcel_IOFactory */
include 'PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';

?>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

<title>PHPExcel Reader Example #02</title>

</head>
<body>

<h1>Chargement fichier Facturation</h1>

<?php

$inputFileName = '../Docs_PDC/FACTURATION_Janvier.xls';

echo 'Loading file ',pathinfo($inputFileName,PATHINFO_BASENAME),' using PHPExcel_Reader_Excel5<br />';
$objReader = new PHPExcel_Reader_Excel5();
//  $objReader = new PHPExcel_Reader_Excel2007();
//  $objReader = new PHPExcel_Reader_Excel2003XML();
//  $objReader = new PHPExcel_Reader_OOCalc();
//  $objReader = new PHPExcel_Reader_SYLK();
//  $objReader = new PHPExcel_Reader_Gnumeric();
//  $objReader = new PHPExcel_Reader_CSV();
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'HTML'); 
$objWriter->save('Facturation.html'); 


echo '<hr />';

$sheetData = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null,true,true,true);
var_dump($sheetData);

$filename = "DownloadReport";
$table    = $_POST['table'];

// save $table inside temporary file that will be deleted later
$tmpfile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'html');
file_put_contents($tmpfile, $table);

// insert $table into $objPHPExcel's Active Sheet through $excelHTMLReader
$objPHPExcel     = new PHPExcel();
$excelHTMLReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('HTML');
$excelHTMLReader->loadIntoExisting($tmpfile, $objPHPExcel);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Facturation'); // Change sheet's     title if you want

unlink($tmpfile); // delete temporary file because it isn't needed anymore

header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-   officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'); // header for .xlxs file
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename='.$filename); // specify  the download file name

exit;


?>
<body>
```

If someone has any idea I'll eternally grateful to him (or her ;) )

I dug a little more on this, and i noticed that: the exception is raised because 
PHPExcel tries to resolve a formula with an Excel reference value (like "P$7") in argument. And the referenced value is not a number, it's just a column name. 
So, Is it possible to disable PHPExcel's formula solving in some fields ? Or is there any other way to get around this ?

Comment: As I already said when you posted this previously, you cannot selectively enable/disable the calculation engine for some cells and not for others

Comment: Did you try using the [formula debugging tools](https://gist.github.com/MarkBaker/5908357) that I pointed you to previously? The output from this might help diagnose the real problem

Comment: @Mark Baker, yeah be sure that I got account out your advice ;), I've just moved the post.

Comment: I'm just tryin' to solve my problem with your error reporting script (thx for it btw).